# Separable subspace of the dual space of $L^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, duality-theorems, separable-spaces

Background: I'm working on a project where the beloved Hilbert space $L^2$ is replaced by $L^1$ and I'm searching for a suitable generalisation of the inner product using duality.

The space of Lebesgue-integrable functions $L^1$ is separable and thus I can choose a (Schauder) basis $(u_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}}$. I know that the dual space of $L^1$ is isometrically isomorphic to $L^\infty$, which is not separable. In particular, the dual set $(u_\alpha^*)_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}}$ is too small to span $L^\infty$. (I do  deliberately identify functionals in $(L^1)^*$ with functions in $L^\infty$ by Riesz theorem.)

My question is: what is $\overline{\mathrm{span}} (u_\alpha^*)_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}}$? How do I need to restrict $L^\infty$ so that the elements of this subspace can be expanded in $(u_\alpha^*)$?

After long research in text books and on the web, some thoughts are:

- one has to  restrict to the continuous dual space, i.e., bounded continuous functions $C_b \subset L^\infty$. But this space is still not separable, so too large
- one may need to remove null functionals from $(L^1)^*$, i.e., divide $L^\infty$ by the annihilator of the set $(u_\alpha) \in L^1$. But I'm not so familiar with factor spaces and have no idea how to proceed ...
- ... ?

After all, would such a separable subspace of $L^\infty$ depend on the choice of $(u_\alpha)$? Even if this is not the case, there may be a "sensible" subspace that is relevant for applications.

If needed, the domain $X$ of the functions in $L^1$ can be assumed to be bounded. However, I believe this is irrelevant as the Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Of course, everything depends on how you choose those $u_\alpha$. Do you have one particular choice in mind?

Comment: Note: contrary to what you seem to be claiming, not every separable Banach space has a Schauder basis.

Comment: @PhoemueX: thanks for pointing this out, I was not aware of it. For the question above it is not important as L^1 does have a Schauder basis.

Comment: @daw: The elements of L^1 shall represent probability densities. So it seems natural to choose basis functions that are non-negative (and indeed such a basis exists: https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.07557).

Comment: The question has a partial answer in this MathOverflow question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248379/separable-subspaces-in-dual-spaces